# “Che t'aggia di'” what does “aggia” mean"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

After listening to this very funny song (with Mina and Celentano) and even though I know what this question means: “*Che t'aggia di'?*” = “What do I have to say to you?”, I still don't know and can't find what “aggia” is or means.
I have been told that this phrase is from Naples.

Comment: You can re-write is as _che ti aggio a dire?_. Well, it is clear that _aggio_ is directly from Latin _habeo_ where _b_ gradually became _gg_. Cfr [here](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-modali_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/) (lo sviluppo di /e/ in semivocale /j/).

Comment: Wrt the meaning, "Che t'aggi' 'a di'" is more similar to the English idioms "What can I tell you?" and "What can I say?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a regional form in "[dialetto pugliese](http://www.languagesbysongs.eu/Che-t-aggia-di.html)" (the dialect spoken in the Apulia region of Italy) of the first person singular in the present tense of the verb "avere" (to have). In standard Italian it would be "Che ho da dirti?" o "Che ti devo dire?"

You can find it in [Wikipedia](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialetto_brindisino#Verbo_Avere_.28Aviri.29).

Comment: molto utile!!!!!!!!

Comment: It is not *pugliese*, it is *napoletano* (from Naples). It takes the riff from an extremely famous song dated 1938 (named "Che t'aggi' 'a di'"). You can find performances by Sergio Bruni or Peppino di Capri.